# How did 1inch token contract get the special address?

Tags: contract-deployment, addresses, exchanges

The [1Inch Exchange](https://app.1inch.io/) token contract address is [`0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302`](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/1inch/), which is the same on *both* [Ethereum mainnet](https://etherscan.io/token/0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302) and [Binance Smart Chain mainnet](https://bscscan.com/token/0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302).

As I understand, when deploying a contract, there is no way to specify an address. Am I wrong?

The two deployments on ETH and BSC are separate, so 1Inch managed to not only get a special contract address for their token, but also did that twice. What techniques can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks So the trick would be to use the same address on multiple networks. You could probably write a script to hash the account address and nonce until it generates an address that contains a pattern that you like. Then you would force that same nonce when deploying it to various networks and it will generate the same vanity address for all of them.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you @Zephyrus it answered my question.

Comment: Still not clear to me... could you please expand?